# Получить глобальную переменную App. Webpack 2 - Marionette

Tags: javascript, webpack, marionette

Хочу получить доступ к переменной **app**. Как это сделать?

> app.js

```
'use strict';

import $ from 'jquery';
import Application from './application';


const App = new Application();


    /**
    * Конфигурация Ajax по умолчанию.
    */
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        statusCode: {}
    });

    exports.app = App;


    /**
    * Аутентификация пользователя и старт приложения.
    */
    App.session.checkAuth({
        complete: function() {
            App.start();
        }
    });
```

Импортирую Application.Martionette.

Экспортирую это приложение как app.

> Application.Marionette object

```
'use strict';

import Backbone from 'backbone';
import $ from 'jquery';
import {Application} from 'marionette';
import SessionModel from 'models/sessionModel';
import Router from './router';
import RouterController from './routerController';

export default Application.extend({


    channelName: 'app',

    region: '#main-content',


    /**
     * Инициализация приложения.
     */
    initialize: function() {
        this.session = new SessionModel();
    },

    /** 
     * Старт приложения
     */
    onStart: function() {
        this.router = new Router({ controller: new RouterController() 
        Backbone.history.start();
    },
});
```

Как видно выше, при старте приложения я регистрирую роуты.
В главном роуте homeController я хочу получить данные о сессии пользователя. То есть: app.session ...
Как я могу получить доступ к app как к переменнной?

> Использую webpack 2.

```
elixir(function(mix) {

    mix.less('index.less').less('app.less');

    mix.webpack(['src/app.js'], {
        output: {
            path            : '/public',
            publicPath      : '/js/',
            filename        : '[name].js'
        },
        module: {
            loaders: [
                {   // babel загрузчик. Преобразую из es6 в es5 для старых браузеров.
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                    // babel?optional[]=runtime
                    loader: 'babel', // 'babel-loader' is also a valid name to reference
                    query: {
                        presets: ['es2015']
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.hbs/,
                    loader: "handlebars-template-loader"
                },
            ]
        },
        resolve: {
            modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
            extensions: ['', '.js'],

            alias: {
                'marionette'            : 'backbone.marionette',
                'underscore'            : 'lodash',
                'module-exports'        : '',
                'backbone.wreqr'        : path.resolve(nodeModulesPath, 'backbone.marionette', 'node_modules', 'backbone.wreqr'),
                'backbone.babysitter'   : path.resolve(nodeModulesPath, 'backbone.marionette', 'node_modules', 'backbone.babysitter'),
                'backbone'              : 'backbone',
                'handlebars'            : 'handlebars/runtime.js',

                'src'               : path.resolve(srcPath),
                'models'            : path.resolve(srcPath, 'models'),
                'controllers'       : path.resolve(srcPath, 'controllers'),
                'modules'           : path.resolve(srcPath, 'modules'),
                'helpers'           : path.resolve(srcPath, 'helpers'),
                'views'             : path.resolve(srcPath, 'resources', 'views'),
                'templates'         : path.resolve(srcPath, 'resources', 'templates'),
            }
        },

    });

    mix.version(['js/main.js', 'css/index.css', 'css/app.css']);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку `webpack` помещает все переменные модуля в замыкание, извне они доступны только при явном `export/import` либо при явном помещении в глобальный контекст.

Вместо

```
exports.app=App;
```

Используйте:

```
window.app = App;
```

Тогда переменная `app` станет глобальной.

Или явно импортируйте ее куда нужно через

```
import app from '(путь)app.js'
```